# Futuro do pretérito composto para indicar acontecimentos não confirmados

Tags: tempo-verbal, regência-verbal

Gostaria de saber se é considerado correto o uso do tempo verbal *futuro do pretérito composto* para contar fatos não confirmados.

Me deparo frequentemente com esse tipo de construção quando leio artigos de jornais e revistas.

Por exemplo, [nesta notícia](https://www.em.com.br/app/noticia/gerais/2018/10/16/interna_gerais,997669/bombeiros-encontram-corpo-de-jovem-estava-desaparecida-rio-do-peixe.shtml), há o seguinte texto:

> De acordo com o Corpo de Bombeiros, um tio da jovem relatou aos agentes que **ela teria saído** sozinha para nadar no Rio do Peixe.

Mas basta digitar "teria saído" no Google para encontrar vários outros exemplos.

Nesses casos, não seriam o pretérito perfeito do indicativo ou o pretérito mais-que-perfeito os tempos corretos?

Por exemplo,

> De acordo com o Corpo de Bombeiros, um tio da jovem relatou aos agentes que **ela havia saído** sozinha para nadar no Rio do Peixe.

ou ainda, se a frase omitisse que foi o tio quem contou o acontecido:

> De acordo com o Corpo de Bombeiros, **ela saiu** sozinha para nadar no Rio do Peixe.

Pois, ao meu ver, quando dizemos "De acordo com alguém", "segundo alguém", etc, já deixamos claro que não há certeza sobre o ocorrido.

Além disso, não me lembro de ter aprendido esse tipo de emprego do futuro do pretérito composto, ou seja, mesmo que não houvesse no texto essa parte "De acordo com o Corpo de Bombeiros", a oração "ela teria saído" ainda me soaria errada.

Comment: Eu estava compondo uma resposta mas terminei pensando que lendo este blogue é melhor que qualquer resposta minha. É engraçadíssimo.  https://agaffeeasavenidas.blogs.sapo.pt/a-gaffe-num-futuro-composto-695603?thread=3598899 Na verdade se usa em vez de alegadamente ou alegar. Esse "teria saído" é muito usado em francês, Será que vem de lá? Le garçon serait sorti a 10 heures: O menino teria sáida as 10 h, para dizer: O menino saiu alegadamente as 10h....

Comment: @Lambie obrigado pelo comentário. No post, ela diz estar perplexa com isso e mostra um tom bem crítico, mas não há citações, fontes ou justificativas para dizer que esse emprego do futuro do pretérito composto é incorreto...

Comment: Eu chamaria esse uso do futuro do préterito composto e do futuro do presente "jornalístico". Veja: http://coral.ufsm.br/lec/01_02/EulaliaL.htm [infelizmente, ela escreveu lied em vez de **lead**]. //O blog português que citei é **sátira** do mal emprego desse tempo ou o seu uso exagerado.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é correto.

Como se observa na própria questão, esse uso é bastante frequente e, de acordo com [o artigo](http://dx.doi.org/10.1590/S1518-76322014000100009) sobre a *dinâmica temporal no jornalismo* (apontado pelo Lambie):

> o futuro do pretérito [...] permite a ele não se comprometer com a veracidade da informação

e também

> se emprega, por exemplo, o futuro do pretérito (posterioridade no subsistema enuncivo da anterioridade) no lugar do presente (concomitância no sistema enunciativo), na busca por mostrar que o acontecimento expresso é hipotético ou imaginário

Além disso, de acordo com Bechara (Moderna Gramática Portuguesa, via [postagem](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-uso-do-futuro-e-do-condicional-para-indicar-suposicao/22206) do Ciberdúvidas):

> O futuro do pretérito se emprega ainda para denotar: [...]
>
> b) **asseveração modesta** em relação ao passado, admiração por um fato se ter realizado:
>
> "Eu *teria* ficado satisfeito com as tuas cartas" [Ribeiro de Vasconcelos].
> "Nós *pretenderíamos* saber a verdade."
> "*Seria* isso verdadeiro?"
>
> c) **incerteza**:
>
> "*Haveria* na festa umas doze pessoas."

E, no [Todoestudo](https://www.todoestudo.com.br/portugues/futuro-do-preterito):

> [O futuro do pretérito composto] pode indicar a **possibilidade** de um fato já ocorrido no passado que poderia vir a acontecer.
>
> Exemplo:
> Com toda essa habilidade, João *teria sido* um ótimo jogador profissional.

A sua sugestão (pretérito perfeito, "ela saiu") é possível, mas não a mais usual para o discurso indireto [[1](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-presente-e-o-preterito-perfeito-no-discurso-indireto/32711), [2](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/transposicao-do-discurso-directo-para-o-indirecto/10362), [3](https://www.infoenem.com.br/discurso-direto-para-discurso-indireto/)], mais recomendado costuma ser mudar o *pretérito perfeito* do discurso direto para *pretérito mais-que-perfeito* no indireto:

> De acordo com o Corpo de Bombeiros, um tio da jovem relatou aos agentes que ela **saíra** / **havia saído** sozinha para nadar no Rio do Peixe.

Quanto a `"segundo alguém", etc, já deixamos claro que não há certeza sobre o ocorrido`, a situação é semelhante a, por exemplo, "Ontem saí cedo.": a palavra "ontem" já indica se tratar de passado, ainda assim, conjuga-se no pretérito.

Comment: Olá. Primeiramente, obrigado pela resposta. Na questão, observei que esse uso é frequente *em um tipo de texto*, normalmente não o encontro em outros lugares. Quantos aos exemplos retirados do Ciberdúvidas, acho que não expressam a mesma coisa. Por exemplo, "Eu teria ficado satisfeito com as cartas" me parece negativo, dando a entender que as cartas não foram recebidas. Enquanto que na reportagem, a frase é mais positiva (em geral, o relato é visto mais como provável, mas não confirmado do que como uma mentira).

Comment: O exemplo "Haveria na festa umas doze pessoas" também não me parece válido. Essa frase é mais ou menos equivalente à "Acho que havia na festa umas doze pessoas", no entanto, sentido questionado na minha pergunta é o de "alegadamente", como a Lambie observou no seu comentário.

Comment: O exemplo do Todoestudo também não me parece análogo, já que, novamente, tenho a impressão de apresentar uma carga mais negativa. A saber, "Com toda essa habilidade, João teria sido um ótimo jogador profissional." me faz pensar que João não conseguiu ser um jogador profissional. Enfim, não vejo muita relação com  "segundo alguém", "alegadamente", etc.

Comment: E quanto ao pretérito mais-que-perfeito, concordo com o dissestes. Me parece mais propício na reformulação que propus.

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira, Eu daria mais atenção às explicações dos sites que aos exemplos. Por exemplo, eu diria que "alegadamente" introduz exatamente a "incerteza" e a "asseveração modesta" do Bechara -- assim como essa minha própria frase ("*eu diria* [...]"). Sobre a conotação 'negativa' comum nos exemplos, ela é natural, porque é mais provável que a pessoa se dê ao trabalho de usar essa construção quando ela explicitamente não quer parecer exprimir concordância. E o "Haveria na festa..." não implica necessariamente um "acho", pelo contrário, pode perfeitamente ser um "afirmou-se".

Comment: Acho que é preciso distinguir uma análise da/de gramática e uma análise de discurso, o que se chama tempo da narração: http://www.scielo.br/pdf/ld/v14n1/09.pdf. Não disponho de tempo para fazê-lo hoje.

Comment: @Lambie, não entendi exatamente o que você quis dizer (mas creio que você elaborará mais tarde), mas me parece que o artigo que você linkou (e.g., em "`se emprega, por exemplo, o futuro do pretérito (posterioridade no subsistema enuncivo da anterioridade) no lugar do presente (concomitância no sistema enunciativo), na busca por mostrar que o acontecimento expresso é hipotético ou imaginário`" e "`o futuro do pretérito (seria), o que permite a ele não se comprometer com a veracidade da informação`"), se alinha com minhas colocações anteriores.

Comment: O assunto é mais do lado da análise de discurso e da estilística. A gramática, já sabemos, cênãoacha?. Veja, por favor, o meu segundo comentário abaixo da pergunta e o link. Eu desisti porqueL tempus fugit. :)